# Add a new notification when push notification is received (not replace the previous)

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

I am using push notifications in my app. I need to display a notification when a push notification delivered. If I send another notification (without clearing the previous notification), it will replace the old notification.

This is the code I use:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
CharSequence tickerText = "New notification Pending";
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, time);
notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

// Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "Notifications";
CharSequence contentText = newMessage;
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
        contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

But I don't want to replace the notification, I want to add it as a new notification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to supply a different ID as the notification ID each time. The best approach would be to send an ID field to GCM which can be then accessed via `Intent.getExtras().getInt()` in your GCMIntentService's onMessage() method.

If this is not possible, I'd suggest using something like `(int)Math.random()*10` to generate a random integer number as your notification ID. This will (partially) ensure that your notifications will not replace each other.

Answer (score 25):

You can also use System.currentTimeMillis() to assign unique id to your notification.

```
int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
mNotificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

Comment: Its an excellent idea. Because time id is never repeated. I use the same in php also. Thanks. But change your code to notify(id, notification); It may be useful for others

Comment: Thanks Indra for mentioning, now I've replaced 1 with id.

Comment: thanqu sir ..for posted it

Answer (score 3):

simple you have to

change Notification id

```
  mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

instead of `1`

for more refer this [**Link**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use a new notification ID every time instead of hardcoding to 1:

```
int i = x; //Generate a new integer everytime
mNotificationManager.notify(i, notification);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what your use case is, but [the Android design guidelines recommend not doing it at all.](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html)

Don't:
[image]
Do:
[image]

Comment: Completely depends on the use case I think, and now thanks to notification channels, one can be more explicit about this

Comment: That's strange. And what if you have several different events in one application, like chat, order confirmation, payment status?

Answer (score 1):

We need Unique notification id which will generate the new notifications.

Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with
      the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

```
  @param id An identifier for this notification unique within your application.
  @param notification A {@link Notification} object describing what to show the user. 
  Must not be null.

public void notify(int id, Notification notification)
{
    notify(null, id, notification);
}
```

Example :

```
int  id =(int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            mNotificationManager.notify(id, notify);
```