# How to show all notification in statusbar until user click in android FCM Like Whatsapp

Tags: android, push-notification, android-pendingintent

As I'm using FCM push notification in my application,Whenever notification comes its showing latest one in status bar,I want to show all notification until user click.If I use pending intent.Flag_current means its showing latest one in android.Please help me.

Service:

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;
    AlertDialog alertDialog = null;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

       // Log.e("BB", "From: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        //  Log.e("BB", "From-: " + remoteMessage.getNotification());

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e("BB", "remoteMessage.getData().toString() " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
           // Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload---: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message

            Log.e("BB", "iff: " +message);

            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);
           // showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), "", message, "", pushNotification, roleid, clickmessage);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
//            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        }else{
            Log.e("BB", "else: " +message);
            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }

    private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
        Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

        try {
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            String title = data.getString("body");
            String message = data.getString("body");
            String roleid = data.getString("role_Id");
            String clickmessage = data.getString("click_action");
           // boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
            //String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
           // String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
          //  JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

         /*   Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
            Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
            Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
            Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
            Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);*/


            if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message

                Log.e("BB", "iff: " + title+message);

                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                // play notification sound
                NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
                //notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, "", pushNotification,roleid,clickmessage);

               /* if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                  } else {
                    // image is present, show notification with image
                    showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, "", pushNotification, "");
                }*/



            } else {

                Log.e("BB", "elsee: " + title+message);
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, "", pushNotification,roleid,clickmessage);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text only
     */
    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String roleid, String clickmessage) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent,roleid,clickmessage);
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text and image
     */
    private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl,String roleid, String clickmessage) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
       // intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl,roleid,clickmessage);
    }
}
```

Notification Util:

```
public class NotificationUtils {

    private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;

    public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String roleid, String clickmessage) {
        showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, null,roleid,clickmessage);
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl,String roleid, String clickmessage) {
        // Check for empty push message
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
            return;


        // notification icon
        final int icon = R.drawable.getspot_logo;





        if(roleid.equalsIgnoreCase("5"))
        {

            intent = new Intent(mContext, ManagerHomePage.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("fromwhere",clickmessage);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);


        }
        else {

            intent = new Intent(mContext, UserHomePage.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("fromwhere",clickmessage);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
        }



       // intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
      /*  final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                );*/
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext);



        final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

            if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {

                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
                } else {
                    showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
                }
            }
        } else {
            showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            //  playNotificationSound();
        }
    }


    private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

        int notifyID = 1;
        String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";// The id of the channel.
        CharSequence name = "Product";// The user-visible name of the channel.
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Log.i("RR","----");
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            // Create a notification and set the notification channel.
            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
                    .setContentTitle("Notification")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.getspot_logo)
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)

                    .build();
            mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager)mContext. getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

// Issue the notification.
            mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID , notification);

        }


        Log.i("RR","elsee----");


        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.addLine(message);

        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)

                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.getspot_logo)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();
       // mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);


    }

    private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
        bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.getspot_logo)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, notification);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading push notification image before displaying it in
     * the notification tray
     */
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Playing notification sound
    public void playNotificationSound() {
        try {
            Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                    + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alarmSound);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method checks if the app is in background or not
     */
    public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }

    // Clears notification tray messages
    public static void clearNotifications(Context context) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

    public static long getTimeMilliSec(String timeStamp) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(timeStamp);
            return date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Note: I want to show all notification to the user, when they click notification it should go ,otherwise all notification i want to display.Please help me.based upon notification only user have to perform task, if old notification is cleared means ,user doesn't know what notificaiton previously came.

Comment: When I click notification it going to same page,if multiple notifcation came means.What to do.anything I have to change in intent.setflag or not.Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You should use a different notifyId for each notification to display them as separate. This already has an answer here [Add a new notification when push notification receives (not replace old one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148076/add-a-new-notification-when-push-notification-receives-not-replace-old-one)

Please search SO before posting a new question.

Comment: thanks for your answer.But if multiple notifcations coming,each notifcation need to go different page ,I'm addding bundle to the intent but latest bundle values only showing when i click that notification,so i cant able to move different screen

Comment: Check this question. Shortly you need to add a different action to each intent or provide a unique id to each pending intent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140072/android-keeps-caching-my-intents-extras-how-to-declare-a-pending-intent-that-ke?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You have hardcoded id used by notification int notifyID = 1;
so each time notification is received the same value (1) is passed into method

```
mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID , notification);
```

making it override the previous one, make sure to pass unique "notifyID" each time you show notification, like, I suggest, make that int notifyID to be static and after showing notification increment value by 1 , or you can use timestamp (timestamp is in long so typecast it to int) and then pass in method.

Hope this helps,

Happy coding... :)

Comment: When I click notification it going to same page,if multiple notifcation came means.What to do.anything I have to change in intent.setflag or not.Please help me

Comment: I'm passing intent ,that is replacing the old one,so if i click notifcation going to same page

Comment: ok, to handle this also pass some data like int or a string which is unique for each page that you want to navigate to on clicking notification, I personally pass int value (from FCM server) which I used to filter and got to know where to navigate to from this particular notification, for eg, :
{data:[{
  broadcaster_id:<broadcaster_id>
 }],
 "read": 0,
 "send_at": "2018-03-09 14:41:58",
 "title": "Message from <username>",
 "image": "s3_url_profile_picture_of_broadcaster",
"user_type": 0,
 "type": 1000
}

here "type: 1000" tells me which type of notification is this...

Comment: yes ,in that response they are giving click action but i want to pass that click action in activity ,if i 'm passing means latest action only i'm getting .

Comment: pass that data via intent extras and receive at activity's end